# How to convert it to JADE template engine?

Tags: node.js, pug

I do not know how can i convert this code:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
    <style>
        .spread{
            font-size: 12px;
        }
    </style>    
<![endif]-->
```

in Jade. Could someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//if IE 9
  style
    .spread{font-size: 12px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Teach a man to fish...

http://html2jade.aaron-powell.com/

Answer (score 0):

You should probably keep it as it is, since jade supports inline html.